# Transport Image tutorial issue: subscriber doesn't show image

Tags: ros, opencv, tutorial, image, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I tried to do the tutorial " Running the Simple Image Publisher and Subscriber with Different Transports " [image_transport/Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials)
but I encountered an issue.

When I run the publisher everything seems to work:

rostopic echo /camera returns a matrix and

rostopic hz /camera proves that something is being published frequently

But then, when I want to use the subscriber which aims to display what is sent to /camera I only have a window(with my wallpaper on it) and then it crashes. I saw I was not the only one with this issue but couldn't find a solution.

So please if you have any idea how to help me it could be great. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261788/transport-image-tutorial-issue:-subscriber-doesn%27t-show-image/) by [Hysis](https://answers.ros.org/users/30395/hysis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out what the error was:
you have to add

```
 cv::waitKey(30);
```

after the imshow in the my_subscriber.cpp, otherwise, windows will just pop infinitely with nothing inside.

---

Originally posted by [Hysis](https://answers.ros.org/users/30395/hysis/) with karma: 16 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0